# How can I get a result from a SQL Query by targeting another row?

Tags: php, sql

I want to run a query say for _profiles

search for row _users that equals "name"

then on that same profile its gets the _ID

I have it connecting.. and I can read the table just don't know how to get 1 rows info by targeting another rows.

anyhelp will be awesome.

its not different tables its the same table..

let me try to explain some more

I want to find out value of Membership_id, where Username equals "bob" in table _profile

Comment: This question is a little vague but I think what you might need is a self-join: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-join#Self-join

Comment: edited the question alittle maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use joins in this case.

Since you have not clearly posted your DB structure, I cant decide which kind of join to apply.

But there are different kind of joins. You can go through [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) link which will make you understand the use of joins ( rows from different tables in single query) in your specific case.